# Master’s in France by holding a student tier 4 visa in Uk

Tags: france, study

Current I am student in London and holding a indian passport. Now I am studying master’s (16month tier 4 student visa). My visa will finish on September 15-2019. Now I am planning to do a another master’s in France. So I If want apply and goto France should I go back to my home country  or I can apply from here?